# Storing Facebook user details using NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm new to swift programming. I'm creating an app with facebook login and it works well. The problem is that, i want to retrieve the user details in some other view controllers. My question is:
 `Is it possible to store the user details and can be fetched to the entire app using NSUserDefaults using swift` 
and if it is then tell the correct way to setting and loading the user details .
In my viewDidLoad()

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(self.facebookReadPermissions, forKey: "User")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

In the login button:

```
@IBAction func btnlogin(sender: UIButton) {

    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(self.facebookReadPermissions, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showView", sender: self)
                self.fetchUserInfo()
                var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

                if let myEmail: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("User") {
                    println(myEmail)
                }

                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fromt he little information provided, i guess you wanted to store the username or some details and then retrieve them on some other ViewControllers later on to either display account information or something else.

It can be done pretty easily and efficiently for small data sizes.

This code snippet will help you save the username, if not present and then retrieve too.

```
 class UserDetail{

//create a singleton
static let sharedInstance = UserDetail()
private init(){}    //make it explicit singleton

func saveUserName(username:String, key:String){
    if let _ = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key){
        return      //we already have
        //or choose to edit it and save it again
    }else{
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(username, forKey: key)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}

func getUserName(key:String)->String?{
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as? String
}

}
```

I basically use singleton and use it from other classes like

```
 class A{
func loginSave(){
    UserDetail.sharedInstance.saveUserName("Bj", key:"username")

}
}

class B{
func loginGet(){
   let name = UserDetail.sharedInstance.getUserName("username")
}
}
```

I hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @kandelvijaya for ur suggestion, actually i want to fetch the user details from facebook like username,email,facebook id. When i logged in using facebook sdk then all the details want to get stored locally and i want to retrieve the values and show as o/p using println statement, so the user details can also be used in some other view controller. is it possible

Comment: yes! NSDefaults is a global container  of key value pair. For each unique key which generally is a string you can have a value of either Int, Double, Char, String, Array of primitives and Dictionary of primitives. Primitives meaning the same old basic data types String, Int, Double.

Comment: okay i got it .. but i don't have any idea to implement the code can you please suggest me .. I added the entire code in the question